# MySQL Query Results in � in WordPress

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

**Background**: I have a WordPress site in development with hosting at BlueHost. It is  a subscription site on which we will publish daily commentary and subscribers can access our extensive html archives and our SQL database.

I am using the WordPress plugin wpDataTables which queries the SQL database to create tables of information on the site.  This plugin works quite well and the tables all display properly including what I think are called "Latin-1 Supplement" characters (e.g., à,è,ï, Õ, etc.) which are the subject of this post. Note that the SQL tables in the database were created, and are updated, using MySQL For Excel. They are stored in the BlueHost SQL default collation: latin1_sweedish_ci.

The Excel worksheets are created by pasting text and dates that originate in MS Word documents. Despite this seemingly convoluted method, everything displays properly on the site, whether inside or outside the tables created by the plugin.

**Source of page with problems**: The wpDataTables plugin does not have the ability to search for multiple terms and display the results in a table with the found terms highlighted.  So I created a WordPress page with three search boxes and two and/or radio buttons between them. I use mark.js to highlight the found search terms. This page creates the tables using the WordPress Insert PHP and SOGO Add Script Header Footer plugins.  All works except for two problems:

**Problem 1**: the table does not display the Latin-1 Supplement characters, rather I get the dreaded �. Note that these characters DO display properly in the portion of the page OUTSIDE the tables. The problem is only in the php mySQL query results inside the tables.

**Problem 2**: there is an additional very peculiar behavior which I hope will be the clue that points at the cause of my problem. Whenever the text "$0" (dollar sign zero) appears in a cell returned by the mySQL query, instead of those two characters, the table displays the search boxes from the top of the page and all of the php code from that page inside that cell of the table instead of "$0". (It also puts this in a nested table within the table cell.) The only reference to "$0" I could find was in connection with preg_replace which I am not using.

**Attempted Solution**: I created a test SQL table with everything (table and all rows) set to UTF-8 general_ci. I uploaded the contents with Excel set as a UTF-8 webpage, and I confirmed that that the contents were coded properly by querying the hex values of the table cells with the à,è,ï, Õ, etc. characters and the hex values for these characters are correct, I think. (e.g., TEXT= áÀ+ÈðÄäüï+ó...; HEX= 20C3A1C3802BC388C3B0C384C3A4C3BCC3AF0A2BC3B30A6020...) The webpage header (meta charset="UTF-8") and the SQL query in the php code (mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');) are both set for UTF-8.

**I think the cause might be**: My guesses are either that: (a) BlueHost may be doing something with the php on the page that is returning characters that the browser doesn't understand. However, I just used the Wordpress plugin Phpinfo() to show my settings and it says that the default_charset is UTF-8. Or possibly (b) when I create the tables from the results of the query, the following code does something wrong [UPDATE: I eliminated the table coding and large block of text still displays �s]:

```
echo "<table border='1'><tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($row as $cell)
    echo "<td>$cell</td>";
    echo "</tr>\n";
```

I have spent countless hours over the past week trying to solve this myself.  I am now ready to hoist the white surrender flag. I have searched through previous questions and answers trying all suggestions with no luck. (Special thanks to Rick James for my education from this page: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll#diagnosing_charset_issues). I would very appreciate any thoughts anyone can provide.